# Is it possible to break captcha?

Tags: captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a CSRF CAPTCHA be defeated?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11768/can-a-csrf-captcha-be-defeated)

Is it to possible break captcha? If yes, how? If no, why websites use difficult captcha systems?

Comment: You might want to try searching for [existing CAPTCHA questions](http://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=captcha) to see if any fit your inquiry.  Particularly [this one](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11768/can-a-csrf-captcha-be-defeated) may be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  CAPTCHA is broken and I have actually used software that breaks it.

I forget the toolkit.  Its on my laptop and I'm at work right now but I just googled and found this one http://code.google.com/p/captcha-breaker/

There have been some successful attacks against reCAPTCHA as well but I think they have been mitigated.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  The most foolproof method is using humans for low wages, who will break ~1000 CAPTCHAs for ~$2.  Certain CAPTCHAs have been broken at various times (though they often get upgraded to become more difficult), but still present a difficult barrier for spammers (who often will go to easier targets instead).